# Passing scope data to Google charts in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, google-visualization

I am working on a stock application using Spring Boot. I have stock data from external API which looks like this:

```
{{stock.dates}} = [2017-05-04, 2017-05-03, 2017-05-02, 2017-05-01, 
2017-04-28, 2017-04-27, 2017-04-26, 2017-04-25, 2017-04-24, 2017-04-21]

{{stock.stockValues}} = [150.85, 151.8, 152.78, 152.46, 150.25, 147.7, 
146.56, 146.49, 145.47, 143.68]
```

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title>Stock app</title>
  <script> 
  <!-- Many scripts here-->
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="App">
  <navbar-menu></navbar-menu>
  <div class="container" ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My stock.html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <script> 
     <!-- Many scripts here-->
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="spinner" class="spinner" ng-show="loading">
    <img src="https://www.yugma.com/images/loading-animation-7.gif" />
</div>


<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container" ng-show="content">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <h5>Stock symbol:</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">{{stock.symbol}}</div>
                <div class="col-md-9"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <h5>Last refreshed:</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">{{stock.lastRefreshed}}</div>
                <div class="col-md-8"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <h5>Last price:</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">{{stock.stockValues[0]}}</div>
                <div class="col-md-8"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My controller.js:

```
(function(angular) {

'use strict';

var App = angular.module('App');

App.controller('StockController', [ '$scope', '$http', '$routeParams',
        '$rootScope', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $rootScope) {

            $scope.init = function() {
                if ($rootScope.stockID !== undefined) {
                    $scope.getStockData($rootScope.stockID);
                    return;
                } else if ($routeParams.stockID !== undefined) {
                    $rootScope.stockID = $routeParams.stockID;
                } else {
                    $rootScope.stockID = 'FB';
                }
                $scope.getStockData($rootScope.stockID);
            };

            $scope.getStockData = function(stockID) {
                $scope.loading = true;
                $scope.content = false;
                $http.get('/stock', {
                    params : {
                        stockID : encodeURI(stockID)
                    }
                }).then(function(response) {
                    $scope.showError = false;
                    $scope.stock = response.data;
                    $scope.stockAvailable = true;

                }, function(response) {
                    $scope.showError = true;
                }).finally(function() {
                    // called no matter success or failure
                    $scope.loading = false;
                    $scope.content = true;

                  });
            };

            $scope.init();

        } ]);
   })(window.angular);
```

Now what I need to do is to create a Google Chart using this data (dates vs stock values) 
How can I do it?

Also, when I tried to draw a static example chart from [Google Charts Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start) I could only do it in my index.html, when I put the same definition in stock.html, the chart didn't work, do you have any idea why?

Comment: chart didn't work, what do u mean by this??u got any error or u cant see the proper output?

Comment: @SaEChowdary I didn't have any error, the chart just didn't show at all.

Comment: okay.....are you loading charts script in that html??where is the chart code in js and where is the id which is used to append chart data to view?